# Robot Framework and Testrail integration

Tags: robotframework, integration, testrail

Can anyone help me with the **Integration of Robot framework and Testrail**. If there is any Youtube or any other tutorials please share.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the commercial solution - [Agiletestware Pangolin](https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin), it can parse Robot xUnit report and upload it into TestRail.
Please have a look at our documentation: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/pangolin-docs/en/latest/

Disclaimer: I'm developing Pangolin